# What does $X \in \mathbb{F}$ mean for $\mathbb{F}$ being a filtration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

I am reading lecture notes which say

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a history, the process $X$ satisfies $X \in \mathbb{F}$ and ...

Now, I know what a history/filtration is, X is, in my understanding, a sequence of random variables. How can I say $X\in\mathbb{F}$? What does it mean?

In general, how can I say that a random variable lies in a sigma algebra?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}=\{\mathscr F_t\}_t$, $X=\{X_t\}_t$. In most cases, we say that $X\in\mathbb F$ if $X_t$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr F_t$ for all $t$.

Comment: This does make sense in the context. My understanding is that this is just a shorthand and it is not $\in \mathbb{F}$ in any literal meaning. Is this correct?

Comment: @user2317602 Yes.